# How to select an audio source (audio input device) React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio, audio-recording

I'm developing an app with the primary function being recording audio snippets that will eventually be processed and returned to the user. I want to be able to force the user's device to record from the built-in microphone. If this is not possible I would like to warn the user that they are recording from a peripheral (hearing aids for example).

I haven't found any packages that expose audio input, and while I'd be open to writing my own I'm wondering if I missed a more obvious solution, as I've been unable to find clear functionality for determining/setting audio source in the native APIs either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this: https://github.com/birdofpreyru/react-native-audio

```
enum AUDIO_SOURCES {
  CAMCODER: number;
  DEFAULT: number;
  MIC: number;
  REMOTE_SUBMIX: number;
  RAW: number;
  VOICE_CALL: number;
  VOICE_COMMUNICATION: number;
  VOICE_DOWNLINK: number;
  VOICE_PERFORMANCE: number;
  VOICE_RECOGNITION: number;
  VOICE_UPLINK: number;
};
```

If you want to force audio input source, then I don't think there is any packages support that, we need to build by ourself by using JNI for android and C++ for iOS.

- Google already supports that: https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/main/docs/FullGuide.md
- iOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptiondefaulttospeaker